# Regex for matching a line using one or multiple words as search key

Tags: java, regex, string

Let`s say we have a string with the following format:

> "part1 part2: part3"

**part1** and **part2** are most of the times a word (including lowercase and uppercase letters) and **part3** can be any combination of numbers and characters (including punctuation). Also, there can be more than one space either before or after the `:`

I am going to write a regex to match such string. For example, if a sample string be like:

```
String sample1 = "Total Amount: $1,000";
String sample2 = "Company: Google Inc.";
```

searching a key like **amount**, **total**, or **total amount** I want to match the *sample1* string. Also searching a key like **company** I want to match *sample2* string.

> EDIT:
>
> As a result, if we have a string like the **sample** above, by searching
>   "Total", "Amount", or "Total Amount" we should return the sample
>   string as a match. And, it is ***important*** that: 1) not only the line should contain the key, but it should also follow the specified format for the line and 2) user enters the **key**.

This is the regex that I have now:

```
String reg = "[tTOoTtAaLl0-9.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~( ) ]+:[A-Za-z0-9.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~( ) ]+";
```

However, my regex does not match the whole line. It is worth pointing out that I use **Java** and assuming the sample string is stored in sample I am using `sample.matches(reg)` to check if the string is a match or not.

Comment: What do you mean with most of the time in "part1 and part2 are most of the times a word"?

Comment: java regex: `^\\w*\\W*\\w*\\W*\\d*\\W*\\d*` this matches these 2 example: `Total Amount: $1,000`
`asdasd asdasd:   $121.11` this works as long as there are only 2 words before the `:`.
if you just want to check if a string contains either amount or total, you can use the `.contains()` method

Comment: Your requirements are not clear, acc. to what you wrote, you may use `"^(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s*:\\s*(.*)"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What do you mean by requirements? Another thing that I can add is that there can be more than one space before and after `:` and I think that is all.

Comment: Ok, then `"^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s*:\\s*(.*)"` can work out. Or a simple [`.split("[\\s:]", 3)`](https://ideone.com/FfoDAP).

Comment: @FlorianH I mean for example instead of a word, part1 or part 2 may be something like "Google." which contains a punctuation or "Google1" which contains a number and they are not necessarily a pure word or vocabulary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What about the key then? for our example, the string should be matched only if we search for "Total", "Amount", or "Total Amount".

Comment: Aha, now you talk requirements... Try `^(Total Amount|Total|Amount)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$`.

Comment: You should edit your question and define exactly (!!) what your samplestring can look like and what exactly (!!) your regula expression should match for!

Comment: The latest edit does not clarify anything. There is no "like" in regex, you should manually code all the possibilities in the pattern. What exact values, list of them, their variations, types of chars, can there be? If you want to match `Total Amount: $1,000`, why should `total` match? What about `Amount`? Be specific, it is regex.

Comment: If you want a string to be match, based on a **special key**, you should exactly know about your **key**

Comment: @k-five I know exactly what the key is. In my case and in sample string, the key can be "Total", "Amount", or "Total Amount"

Comment: @FlorianH I edited the question and I think now that is all I am looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood properly your requirements but here you have 2 examples based on your data and what I guess you want to get:

1) Example for get only the amount of dollars: https://regex101.com/r/7P2Bad/3

2) Example for getting the full String that matches: https://regex101.com/r/7P2Bad/2

*take into account that using Java (not the same syntax as regex101.com has) regex you should escape some characters.*

Working with cases like:

```
aaa bbb!   : $34 
Total Amount: $1,000
njhjh hjh: $33
Google Google1: $100
```

.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Case1: Getting full string
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(.*\\s?.*:\\s?\\$.*)");
    Matcher matcher1 = p1.matcher("Total Amount: $1,000");
    if (matcher1.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Full string matched: " + matcher1.group(1));
    }

    // Case2: Getting only the amount of dollars
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(".*\\s?.*:\\s?\\$?(.*)");
    Matcher matcher2 = p2.matcher("Total Amount: $1,000");
    if (matcher2.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Amount only from matched string: " + matcher2.group(1));
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
Full string matched: Total Amount: $1,000
Amount only from matched string: 1,000
```

---

**EDITED AFTER COMMENT:**

Then, after reading your comment you want something like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userKey = "Amount";
    System.out.println("Full string matched: " + getMatch(userKey));

    userKey = "total";
    System.out.println("Full string matched: " + getMatch(userKey));
}

private static String getMatch(String key) {
    // Case: Getting full string for userKey (case insensitive) matches
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(String.format("(?i)(.*%s.*\\s?.*:\\s*?\\$.*)", key));
    Matcher matcher1 = p1.matcher("Total Amount: $1,000");
    if (matcher1.matches()) {
        return matcher1.group(1);
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

Output:

```
Full string matched: Total Amount: $1,000
Full string matched: Total Amount: $1,000
```

Explanation:

- **(?i)** > search for case insensitive
- **%s** > Just put `userKey` var in that %s placeholder using String.format method

Comment: I want something like: if user enters a key like "Amount" or "Total" or "Total Amount" the line "Total Amount: $1,000" be returned as a match. The only thing missing in your regex is the search key and that is my main problem. How should we include these keys in regex to find the line as a full match?

Comment: I've added another solution that I guess 'matches' your needs. Hope it help :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just a quick question: what if we have sth like: "Company: Google Inc." and search key be "company" it seems  that current regex does not work for this one. In other words, part3 is not necessarily a number with dollar sign. EDIT: just figured: we should simply remove that `\\$`